# Any way to know the cluster size for a hard drive formatted in exFAT?

Tags: hard-drive

Any way to know the cluster size for a hard drive formatted in exFAT?.  I tried with DriveDX too, not said.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specified a cluster size when formatting the drive (which I assume you did not as you would then know it) the cluster size varies by the size of the drive being formatted. And since you didn't include the size of your drive in your question you will have to refer to the table [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat) (scroll down a ways to exFAT) to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I know that table.  I just would like to know what's the cluster size if I don't know that.  Thanks.

Comment: That table shows you one other thing, unless you specifically *set* the cluster size *the cluster size is a variable* and changes depending on the size of the storage device